# Scala reduce a List based on a condition

Tags: list, scala, reduce

I have a List of certain type that I want to reduce based on a condition. I have a type where the Interval is a DateTime interval with a start and an end:

```
case class MyType(a: Interval, value: Double)
```

I have got a List[MyType] entries that I want to reduce to a List[MyType] based on MyType that contains same DateTime and value. I do not want to go over the List twice which I already do.

Say I have:

```
val a = MyType(interval1, 2)
val b = MyType(interval2, 2)
val c = MyType(interval3, 1)
val d = MyType(interval4, 6)
val e = MyType(interval5, 2)

val original = List(a, b, c, d, e)
```

I have to now reduce the original List based on the following conditions:

```
1. interval should be continuous, then take the start of the first entry and the end of the second entry
2. the double value should be the same
```

So assuming that interval1, interval2 are continuous, the result should look like:

```
val result = Seq(MyType(new Interval(a.interval.start, b.interval.end),2), c, d, e)
```

Is there a much more elegant solution or an idea?

Comment: What does "contain same DateTime and value" mean? "Same" as what? Can you provide a sample of the input and output?

Comment: That doesn't really help. You didn't provide a sample of the output, and I don't know what `interval1`, `interval2`, etc. are. And again you said `the double value should be the same`, but again - same as what? A predefined value? You may want to take a look at this page from the Help Centre: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added what I expect as a result!

Comment: So, you want to *merge* instances of `MyType` that are contiguous (where `x` and `y` are contiguous if and only if `x.interval.end == y.interval.end`). Instances that cannot be merged with either neighbor, return them untouched. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right!, but the condition is x.interval.end.equals(y.interval.start)

Comment: If `a` can be continued by both `b` and `e`, is it important, which to choose? Or the first acceptable case would work?

Comment: He is doing premature optimization. And he literally required one hour of our time to even explain what he wants. Proposed: Closing the question as not clear.

Comment: I like the question :) It's a good example of logic with intervals!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the reduce function, check if the condition is true, and if it is, return the current accumulator instead of what would you otherwise compute.

Here's how you would sum only even numbers:

```
Seq(1,4,6,3).foldLeft(0)( (acc, a) =>
    if (a % 2 == 0) acc + a else acc
)
res5: Int = 10
```

**Response to the edited question:** It appears you have some conditions that have to hold about the consecuitve elements. Then you can apply the function `.sliding`.

```
Seq(a,b,c,d,e).sliding(2).foldLeft(0)(
    case (acc, Seq(MyType(ai, a), MyType(bi, b))) =>
        if (ai.max == bi.min) acc + a else acc
)
```

**Buuut...** You have probably guessed it would not be as performant as you would like. I hope you are not doing any premature optimization, because you know, that's the root of all evil. But if you really need performance, rewrite the code in terms of `while` loops (fall back to Java).

Comment: Don't know why the downvotes.  Based on the limited info in the question this is a valid solution.

Comment: I have modified my question! Sorry for not being explicit in my first attempt!

Comment: Probably downvotes come due to: 1 it doesn't work (if `a` and `c` are continuous and `b` is somewhere else. 2 it's not clear, what is `acc`. (I have not downvoted :) )

Comment: This answer was made after his second edit. Now he has edited the question for the third time.

Comment: `sliding` is a very cool fn.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
def reduce(xs: List[MyType]) = {
  xs match {
    case a :: b :: tail =>
      if(a.interval.end == b.interval.start && a.value == b.value)
        reduce(MyType(new Interval(a.interval.start, b.interval.end) a.value) :: tail)
      else
        a :: reduce(b :: tail)
    case _ => xs
  }
}
```

The `if` condition might need minor tweaking depending on your exact needs, but the algorithm should work.

1. Given a list `xs`

   1. If the first two items `a` and `b` can be merged into `c`, merge them and go back to step 1 with `xs = c :: tail`
   2. If `a` and `b` cannot be merged, try reducing all elements but the first, and append the result to `a`
   3. Otherwise (list has 1 element or is empty), return `xs`

Comment: It will not work on unsorted and on overlapping intervals. Imagine `1st` and `3rd` items are mergable, but `2nd` is somewhere else or have different value.

Comment: @OlegRudenko Is that a requirement? If so, it was not stated in the question (which was as vague as vague can be to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

Pay attantion that your task could result in multiple distinct solutions, which cannot be further reduced.
So as result you will get a set of solutions: `Set[Set[MyType]]`

I use `Set[MyType]` instead of proposed `List[MyType]` and `Seq[MyType]` because order is not important and my answer needs possibility to compare different solutions (in order to avoid duplicates).

My answer doesn't make assumptions about order of items, any order is OK.

Besides that in order to simplify the code I have replaced `Interval` with 2 fields `from` and `to`, which can be easily converted.

Here is the code for reduction:

```
case class MyType(from: Long, to: Long, value: Double)

object MyType {
  //Returns all possible varians of reduced source.
  //If reduction is not possible, returns empty set.
  private def strictReduce(source: Set[MyType]): Set[Set[MyType]] = {
    if (source.size <= 1) {Set.empty} else {
      val active = source.head //get some item
      val otherItems = source.tail //all other items
      val reducedWithActive: Set[Set[MyType]] = otherItems.flatMap {
          case after if active.to == after.from =>
            //we have already found a reduction (active->after),
            //  so further reductions are not strictly required
            reduce(otherItems - after + MyType(active.from, after.to, active.value))
          case before if before.to == active.from =>
            //we have already found a reduction (before->active),
            // so further reductions are not strictly required
            reduce(otherItems - before + MyType(before.from, active.to, active.value))
          case notContinuos => Set.empty[Set[MyType]]
        }
      //check if we can reduce items without active
      val reducedIgnoringActive = strictReduce(otherItems).
        //if so, re-insert active and try to reduce it further, but not strictly anymore
        flatMap (reducedOther => reduce(reducedOther + active))
      reducedWithActive ++ reducedIgnoringActive
    }
  }
  //Returns all possible varians of reduced source.
  //If reduction is not possible, returns source as single result.
  private def reduce(source: Set[MyType]): Set[Set[MyType]] = strictReduce(source) match {
    case empty if empty.isEmpty => Set(source)
    case reduced => reduced
  }
  //Reduces source, which contains items with different values
  def reduceAll(source: Set[MyType]): Set[Set[MyType]] = source.
    groupBy(_.value). //divide by values, because they are not merge-able
    mapValues(reduce). //reduce for every group
    values.reduceLeft((solutionSetForValueA, solutionSetForValueB) =>
    //merge solutions for different groups
    for(subSolutionForValueA <- solutionSetForValueA;
      subSolutionForValueB <- solutionSetForValueB)
      yield (subSolutionForValueA ++ subSolutionForValueB) //merge subSolutions
    )
}
```

And here is the sample, which uses it:

```
object Example extends App {
  val source = Set(
    MyType(0L, 1L, 1.0),
    MyType(1L, 2L, 2.0), //different value
    MyType(1L, 3L, 1.0), //competing with next
    MyType(1L, 4L, 1.0), //competing with prev
    MyType(3L, 5L, 1.0), //joinable with pre-prev
    MyType(2L, 4L, 2.0), //joinable with second
    MyType(0L, 4L, 3.0) //lonely
  )

  val solutions: Set[Set[MyType]] = MyType.reduceAll(source)
  //here you could choose the best solution (for example by size)
  //printing out
  solutions.foreach(solution => println(solution.toList.sortBy(_.from).sortBy(_.value).
      map(item => s"${item.from}->${item.to}(${item.value})").mkString(", ")))
}
```

My result is:

```
0->5(1.0), 1->4(1.0), 1->4(2.0), 0->4(3.0)
0->4(1.0), 1->5(1.0), 1->4(2.0), 0->4(3.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
  def reduce(accumulator: Seq[MyType], original: Seq[MyType]): Seq[MyType] = original match {

    case Nil => accumulator
    case head :: xs => {
      val found = xs.find(_.timeSpan.getStart().equals(head.timeSpan.getEnd))
      if (found.isDefined && found.get.value == head.value) {
        reduce(
          accumulator :+ (MyType(new Interval(head.timeSpan.getStart, found.get.timeSpan.getEnd), head.value)),
          original.diff(Seq(found.get, head))
        )
      }
      else
        reduce(
          accumulator :+ head,
          xs
        )
    }
  }
```